# Windows CMD run a command and inject the date

Tags: windows-command-prompt

I have the following command:

`c:\run.exe >> c:\log.txt`

I actually want:
`c:\run.exe >> c:\log_19-07-2016.txt`

Can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I stole from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334618/how-to-get-mm-dd-yyyy-in-dos-batch-file) for you after discovering the old batch assets I had lying around used a different date format and therefore didn't give the right format.  Add this to the top of your script:

```
for /f %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^|find "20"') do set dt=%%I
REM dt format is now YYYYMMDDhhmmss...
set dt=%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~2,2%-%dt:~0,4%

set outfile = "c:\log_%dt%.txt"
```

Then use:

```
c:\run.exe >> %outfile%
```

instead of the other command.